# Zipfile password recovery program

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

I would like to get a few tips on how to improve this program, which is supposed to help recovering lost passwords from .zip files.

```
import zipfile
import string
import itertools
import random
import time

"""
Zipfile password cracker using a dictionary attack and, if not successful, 
switches to bruteforce
"""

def crack(zipfilename,dictionary):

    t0=time.time()
    password = None
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation 

    #Tries at first a dictionary attack 

    with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            password_string = line.strip('\n')
            try:
                password = bytes(password_string, 'utf-8')
                zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
                t1=time.time()
                total = t1 - t0
                print('Password found : %s' %password_string)
                print('Time spent : %f seconds' %total)
                return
            except:
                pass

    #If the password hasn't been found yet, the function switches to bruteforce

    nbcharmax = 10 #Maximum length to test

    for i in range(1,nbcharmax):
        print('Testing length = %i' % i)
        for j in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i):
            try:
                password_string=''.join(j)
                password = bytes(password_string, 'utf-8')
                zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
                t1=time.time()
                total = t1 - t0
                print('Password found : %s' %password_string)
                print('Time spent : %f seconds' %total)
                return
            except:
               pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    crack('test.zip','dictionary.txt')
```

So now the program seems to work fine but is a bit slow in my opinion. I'm wondering if there's a faster way than `zip_file.extractall()` to open archive files?

Comment: Welcome to Codereview! This is a nice first question, but I'd suggest you remove the last one, as it's off-topic here. We would gladly improve your working code but unfortunately asking us to add new functionality is "_forbidden_".

Comment: Alright, I edited my post following your advice !

Comment: I don't think the speed problem is down to the zip file library; working through the Cartesian product of 94 characters is going to take a while. For a length of ten, there are `54,440,667,446,151,152,650` passwords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Follow the styleguide ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

- don't import modules which you're not using (`random`)
- more, imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.
- I always like to put my imports in alphabetical order, so that it gets easier to find them.
- you should have two newlines before defining your methods
- you should also have a space after every `,`
- you should put a space before and after operators (`x = 'something'`); this is not required when defining arguments.
- instead of commenting code in the middle of the method, try to split the logic of your program in separate functions.
- you should be using the new `.format()` style

#### 2. Working on the code:

- you should really let the user choose where the files actually are
- don't use bare `except`s.
- you can directly use `.encode()` if you want to convert a string to bytes. That's actually the pythonic way of doing it as per this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)
- when reading a file, you can omit the `r` mode, as that's the default one

#### 3. Efficiency

The problem does not come from the `zip` module but rather from the cartesian product you're doing. As @jonsharpe mentioned in his comments, your program has to go through **a lot** of passwords.

The final code would look like this:

```
"""
Zipfile password cracker using a dictionary attack and, if not successful, 
switches to bruteforce
"""

import itertools
import string
import time
import zipfile


ARCHIVE_PATH = 'test.zip'
DICTIONARY_PATH = 'dictionary.txt'


def dictionary_attack():
    """Tries at first a dictionary attack"""

    t0 = time.time()
    with open(DICTIONARY_PATH) as f:
        for password in f:
            password = password.rstrip().encode()
            try:
                zipfile.ZipFile(ARCHIVE_PATH).extractall(pwd=password)
                t1 = time.time()
                print('Password found: {}\nTime spent: {} seconds'.format(password.decode(), t1 - t0))

                return True
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
    return False


def bruteforce_attack(nbcharmax):
    """If the password hasn't been found yet, the function switches to bruteforce"""

    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(1, nbcharmax):
        for j in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i):
            password = ''.join(j).encode()
            try:
                zipfile.ZipFile(ARCHIVE_PATH).extractall(pwd=password)
                t1 = time.time()
                print('Password found: {}\nTime spent: {} seconds'.format(password.decode(), t1 - t0))

                return True
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not dictionary_attack():
        bruteforce_attack(4)
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need extract all to find the password because it will take more time to extract files.

Use `Zipfile.setpassword()` with `ZipFile.testzip()` to check password.

`testZip()` will return `None` if file can be unzipped and return the filename if cannot be unzipped.

```
def dictionary_attack(self, zip_file_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zf:
        self.logger.debug(zf.infolist())
        with open(DICTIONARY_PATH, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                password = line.strip('\n').encode()
                # self.logger.debug("Try " + str(password))
                try:
                    zf.setpassword(password)
                    if zf.testzip() is None:
                        self.logger.debug('Password found: {}'.format(password.decode()))
                        return password.decode()
                except RuntimeError:
                    pass
                except zlib.error as e:
                    self.logger.error(str(e))

        return
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [@Dex'ter's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160834/98493), there is still quite a bit of duplication there. The whole output and the actual testing of the password as well as the timing output could be factored out to separate functions, like this:

```
"""
Zipfile password cracker using a dictionary attack and, if not successful, 
switches to bruteforce
"""

import itertools
import string
import time
import zipfile


ARCHIVE_PATH = 'test.zip'
DICTIONARY_PATH = 'dictionary.txt'
ALPHABET = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation


def timeit(f):
    """A decorator to print the time a function took to run"""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """The wrapper that is run instead of the function"""
        t0 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        t1 = time.time()
        print('Time spent: {} seconds'.format(t1 - t0))
        return ret
    return wrapper


@timeit
def crack(zip_file, attack, max_chars=-1, **kwargs):
    """
    Tries to crack the password of the `zip_file` using the `attack`
    function.

    Tries only passwords up to `max_chars` length.
    Passes any additionaly keyword arguments on to the `attack` function.
    """
    for password in attack(max_chars, **kwargs):
        try:
            zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file).extractall(pwd=password)
            print('Password found: {}'.format(password.decode()))
            return True
        except RuntimeError:
            pass
    return False


def dictionary_attack(max_chars, dictionary=DICTIONARY_PATH):
    """
    Yields passwords from a `dictionary` file
    less than length `max_chars` or any length if `max_chars == -1`.
    """

    with open(dictionary) as f:
        for password in f:
            password = password.rstrip().encode()
            if max_chars == -1 or len(password) <= max_chars:
                yield password


def bruteforce_attack(max_chars, alphabet=ALPHABET):
    """
    Yields all combinations of letters in the `alphabet` with 
    increasing length until `max_chars` is reached.
    """
    if max_chars == -1:
        raise ValueError("You have to specify a upper bound for the length of the password. Otherwise this could run forever.")

    for i in range(1, max_chars):
        for j in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=i):
            yield ''.join(j).encode()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not crack(ARCHIVE_PATH, dictionary_attack):
        crack(ARCHIVE_PATH, bruteforce_attack, max_chars=4)
```

This way you can just pass the different configuration options down to the function actually cracking the password (so changing the path of the dictionary file on-the-fly is as easy as calling `crack(ARCHIVE_PATH, dictionary_attack, dictionary="path/to/other.dict")` and using another alphabet is `crack(ARCHIVE_PATH, bruteforce_attack, alphabet="abc"`).

I used a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) to add the output for the timing, which is easy to re-use.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Any idea why I get a `BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'test.txt'` error if I don't catch all exceptions though ? Same happened with @Dex'ter's code. Actually that was the reason why I let bare `except`s in my program at first...

Comment: @Aegir Seems like the `RuntimeError` is not the right exception to catch. Try `except BadZipFile` instead?

Comment: Alright, I tried and it looks like I have to catch both exceptions (`RuntimeError` and `BadZipFile`), but even then I get a new error which is like `error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back`, and I can't find any documentation about it online.

Comment: @Aegir Sorry, I have never used `zipfile` before either...But have you checked that it works when supplying the correct password? As in `def correct(*args): yield "secretPassword"`, `crack(ARCHIVE_PATH, correct)`? Because it sounds like you might have [a corrupted file](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2012-01/msg00033.html).

Comment: @Aegir Also, you don't happen to run [ESET NOD32 antivirus](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1598999.html)?

Comment: I made several tests to make sure it doesn't come from a corrupted file, but the problem remains. It works fine when I supply the correct password though, and I'm not running ESET NOD32 antivirus. Well, all things considered, I might let `except Exception` in my code since I read it is still better than a bare `except` and I have no clue what other Exception I should catch otherwise to prevent that `BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'test.txt'` error.

Comment: @Aegir Then I (and the first few Google results for this error) are out of ideas for now...Indeed catching `Exception` is significantly better than a bare `except`, especially for your code. It means you can still abort it with CTRL-C if you run the brute Force attack with a too high character limit.